# Socket OutputStream(BufferedWriter) not flushing msg

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream, flush

Using a simple client I'm trying to send console input through a `Socket`'s `OutputStream`:

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {

    Thread input = new Thread(() -> {
        String msg;
        try {
            while ((msg = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    input.start();

    String msg;
    try {
        while ((msg = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.write(msg);
            out.flush(); // not flushing?
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I't seems that the stream is not flushing until I send an `END OF INPUT` after which I receive all previous attempts as one long `String` on the server side but also terminates the client.

Using `PrintWriter` instead of `BufferedWriter` yields the same result.

**Why the data is not going trough until an `END OF INPUT`(^Z) is read from `std in`?**

Comment: Why is there an opening bracket at the end of `stdIn` declaration?

Comment: @3kings Because it should be there since it opens the `try` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a line terminator to the message when you write it.